# What is the correct way to add this field to this entity?

Tags: java, oop, mongodb, entity

I have this entity

```
public class location{

   private String name;
   private final Set<String> subLocations = new HashSet<String>();

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }
   // corresponding setter

   public void addSubLocations(String subLocation){
      subLocations.add(subLocation);
   }
   public Set<String> getSubLocations(){
      return subLocations;
   }
}
```

This class will get populated and then stored into a Mongo DB Collection.

We have a requirement of adding a new field called "organization_group". Logically, this belongs under a subLocation, so I would like to add it there.

What I pasted is the class as it is right now. What is the best way of adding the 'group' child to sublocations? Would it be to create a SubLocation class?

Just need some input on this,

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what any of these fields mean, it's impossible to give an informed opinion on how they should be grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer your question, Whats the difference between Location and Sub Location ? With the single field Name, for me both the class definitions look the same.

are you aware of [Composite Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) ? if the Location class needs to be represent a tree like data, you should consider using composite pattern.

now to answer your question, I believe you are thinking in the right direction, adding a field called organizationGroup to a new SubLocation class is the right way to go for most situations.

Comment: The difference between Location and Sub Location is essentially "State" / "City" respectively for this data.

Comment: In that case i believe Location represent a tree like data, i think you should create a super "Location" class, and 2 different subclasses one specific for State and another for City (with organization_group as a field), while maintaining a Composite pattern.